# How to binding XDocument element to combobox in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, xelement

I have a XDocument read from xml file:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Product> _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@".\Config\MCU.xml");
        foreach (XElement productRow in doc.Root.Elements("MCU"))
        {
            var m = new Product(productRow.Element("MCUName").Value, Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("MCUNumber").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("FlashAddress").Value),
                Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("PageCount").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("PageSize").Value), productRow.Element("BinFile").Value,
                Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("RAMCodeAdd").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("MainCR").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("CRTrimmingAdd").Value),
                Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("CRTrimmingLength").Value), Convert.ToUInt32(productRow.Element("UIDAdd").Value), Convert.ToByte(productRow.Element("UIDLength").Value),
                productRow.Element("UID").Value, productRow.Element("UserArea").Value);

            _products.Add(m);
        }
        return _products;
    }
```

Now I want to binding **XElement** `MCUName` to combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_MCUType" SelectedItem="{Binding MCUName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

ItemsSouce in the code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cb_MCUType.ItemsSource = App.ProductDb.GetProducts();
    }
```

But this doesn't work, the combobox populate the `Product`, how should I fix this? Thanks!

### Update:

Thanks for the replies. As you suggested, now I would like to write this in MVVM, so I change my original code:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_MCUType" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProduct}" DisplayMemberPath="MCUName" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ProductDB pd = new ProductDB();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
       DefaultValue_Load();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }

    private Product _selectedProduct; 
    public Product SelectedProduct 
    { 
       get { return _selectedProduct; } 
       set
       {
          _selectedProduct = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct"); 
       }
    }

    public void DefaultValue_Load()
    {

        ProductsList = new ObservableCollectioin<Product>(pd.GetProducts());
    }
}
```

Comment: try Adding DisplayMemberPath="MCUName" in your combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Products` in `GetProducts()` you provide `MCUName` as the first parameter in the constructor. For the following sample, I'll assume, that there is a property `McuName` on every product:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cb_MCUType.ItemsSource = App.ProductDb.GetProducts().Select(p => p.McuName);
}
```

It is worth to mention, that this is not a clean MVVM implementation. You should consider to redesign your application to follow the MVVM patter.

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Comment: no, this DisplayMemberPath="MCUName" is better because you keep the object, not only the string MCUName

Comment: @GCamel that totally depends on the usecase. I agree, that there are plenty where I would use `DisplayMemberPath` but that is not what OP asked for.

Comment: ok, ok, no criticism. But i am sure he will have to work with his products and the string will not be enough to identify

Comment: @GCamel That will be another problem and then there is room for another question of him ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your guys' replies. Please see my update. How I should fix the code in MVVM?